# How to implement a superclass/subclass structure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

These are the tables in my database, I need to create a couple superclass/subclass structures.

The first is where...

Superclass-Crew_Member

Subclasses-Director, Producer, Other_Directing, Other_Production, Art, Camera, Sound, Grip, Electrical, Post.

The second is...

Superclass-Producer

Subclasses-Salaries, Budget

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_film_crew |
+---------------------+
| art                 |
| budget              |
| camera              |
| crew_member         |
| director            |
| electrical          |
| equipment           |
| grip                |
| location            |
| manufacturer        |
| other_directing     |
| other_production    |
| post_production     |
| producer            |
| salaries            |
| sound               |
+---------------------+
```

So how exactly would I go about creating those relationships?

Edit:

Maybe I should have clarified some other things too.

Here's what's contained in crew_member (Superclass):

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Member_ID   | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| Member_Name | varchar(25) | YES  |     | [INSERT EXAMPLE]  |                |
| DOB         | date        | YES  |     | [INSERT EXAMPLE]  |                |
| Address1    | varchar(25) | YES  |     | [INSERT EXAMPLE]  |                |
| Address2    | varchar(25) | YES  |     | [INSERT EXAMPLE]  |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Meanwhile here's what's contained in Other_Directing (Example Subclass):

```
+---------------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| O_Director_ID | int(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FAD_ID        | int(5) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SAD_ID        | int(5) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SUD_ID        | int(5) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now all the foreign keys are referring to Member_ID from Crew_Member. All the other tables (except Director and Producer) are created in similar ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by following some general rules which have to be taken in consideration when creating a database. Put the information that different groups have in common in 1 table and the specific data in smaller satellite tables.

I would put the generic information about a crew member in the first table:
so we would have an id, name, address and whatever all the members have in common.
Then you create "sub-tables" which relate to the "crew-member" table through the value crew_member_id. In this tables you put only the specific information related to directors, producers etc..

So the fields here might be something like: id, crew_member_id, directed movies, etc..

Even with the superclass producer you should work in the same way. Relate the subtales with the superclass through its primary key to have relations between them.

I would suggest you to read some articles about database designing. It might save your life in the future, cause after a database is made then it becomes much harder to correct mistakes.

http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html

Comment: Thank you for the information, but clearly I should have been more specific. 

I've added more detailed information, which I believe correlates with how you're saying it needs to be constructed; what I don't actually understand is how to create those relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a really good question, that I was researching as well.

The ideas I came up with were:
1> Have a parent table as the super class with sattelite tables for the attributes for each subclass joined by a foreign key.  You could then represent it as a view.

2> Have a parent table as the super class and another single table for all of the extra attributes.  This would have to be matched by joined by two foreign keys.

3> One table which holds all of the classes.(Terrible idea)

Theres other ideas but I think the first is the best bet.

Here's more info that suggests the first way.

http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php